# protoc-gen-js: program not found or is not executable

Tags: grpc, protoc, grpc-web

Trying to compile my protos - I need to compile them to use in my react app. But I get this error. I run the command as follows:

```
cd src/main/proto && protoc -I=. *.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

Where can I find protoc-gen-js? I didn't come across any repo for it.

Comment: I think that JavaScript code generation is now built-in to `protoc`. Are you running a recent version of `protoc`? What does `protoc --version` yield?  See [releases](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases). `protoc` does match e.g. `--go_out` to `protoc-gen-go` for **external** plugins but, it should not need to do this for JavaScript.

Comment: @DazWilkin yes, its a recent version, I have this installed `libprotoc 3.21.1`

Comment: @DazWilkin do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Interesting..... See: [Issue #10114](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10114)

Comment: I have `protoc` 3.19.4 and that includes `protoc-gen-js`. You could revert to that, or chop through versions to find where it 'broke" (perhaps try 21.0?)

Comment: Found this too [JavaScript support (May 2022)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#javascript). Was trying to understand the change from 3.20 to [4].21

Comment: I previously had `libprotoc 3.17.1` and it caused the same issue

Comment: @DazWilkin this issue exists only on Ubuntu - my coworkers who are using windows report no issues

Answer (score 30):

As of July 2022, there is a known bug in `protoc` versions `21.1` and `21.2` (and `libprotoc 3.21.1` and `libprotoc 3.21.2`).

See [protobuf issue #10114](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10114).

For now, recommend downgrading to version `20.1` (`libprotoc 3.20.1`).

Comment: indeed, I had the same issue, downgrading solved it

Comment: How do I downgrade?

Comment: Thanks for the link! One year later the issue still isn't fixed though. But for now, it looks that like somebody made the plugin available, so you can install it manually as described in the comments there, which might be a better solution than downgrading.

Answer (score 21):

run this command this command will globally install protoc-gen-js

```
  npm install -g protoc-gen-js
```

Answer (score 13):

For Mac users using brew and the provided link by Christopher Peisert
what worked for me was the suggested workaround:

```
$brew install protobuf@3

$brew link --overwrite protobuf@3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install this package globally or in the project devDependencies.

NPM

```
npm install -g protoc-gen-js
// or
npm install protoc-gen-js --save-dev
```

YARN

```
yarn global add protoc-gen-js
// or
yarn add protoc-gen-js --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Can downgrade to @3 versions
Please refer
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/704#issuecomment-1215965557

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34629931)